# I am getting error TS2339: Property 'total' does not exist on type any[]

Tags: angular, typescript

Here is the snippet.  Please help me with this.

```
 response: any[] = [];
proResponse: any[] = [];


 erase(res: any[]): void {res.length = 0; this.response.total = 0; }


 onSubmit(searchForm: FormGroup) {

       this.showNhide = true;
       this.proResponse = [];
       this.proName = '';
       this.searchService.searchNResult(searchForm.value).subscribe((result: any[]) => {
      console.log('Result comes' + result.toString());
      this.response = result;
    }, (error: any) => {
      console.log('search result Loading Error :' + error);
    });
  }
```

Comment: Try declaring `response` as type `any` instead of `any[]`;

Comment: You've declared `this.response` as an array, and an array normally doesn't have a `total` field.  What is the actual structure of the response from the service?  With some more information, we might be able to help you achieve what you intend.

Comment: Hi Mr. Matt,  This response is in the form of object which contains as:data: Array(9)
0: {phrase: "care & cure"}
1: {phrase: "provided unparallel care"}
2: {phrase: "post-operative care"}
3: {phrase: "showing care & forethought"}
4: {phrase: "do-care , not don't care response is required"}
5: {phrase: "not don't-care but do-care attitude is required"}
6: {phrase: "provided with palliative care"}
7: {phrase: "elder care homes & hospices"}
8: {phrase: "spoke less & with great care"}
length: 9
__proto__: Array(0)
total: 9
__proto__: Object

Comment: result = {total:9, data: Array(9) }

Answer (score 0):

It should be response type of **`any`** not **`any[]`**.It should be as follows,

```
this.searchService.searchNResult(searchForm.value).subscribe((result: any) => {
      console.log('Result comes' + result.toString());
      this.response = result;
    }, (error: any) => {
      console.log('search result Loading Error :' + error);
});
```

Comment: Hi Sajeetharan,  I am getting response in this form..   I am posting it........................data: (9) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
total: 9
__proto__: Object.....It is like json objects in array and I need to access total property here

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
response: any = [];
```

Instead of using

```
response: any[] = [];
```